# Replace a string with regular expression

Tags: regex, string, lua, lua-patterns

I need a help with Lua and regular expression to solve the following problem. I got many strings in the following format:

```
"|keynameN=value"
```

It may contain several spaces between the vertical bar (`|`) and the "keyname". Also, it may contain several spaces between the keyname and the equal symbol (`=`).

1. `"|house10=true"`
2. `"|car11 = house"`
3. `"| name    = car"`
4. `"|     wow15  = cat"`

I need to use `string.gsub()` function passing a regexp that dynamically replaces only the name of each key (`house10`, `car11`, `name`, `wow15`) with my owns, preserving its suffix numbers, and without changing the format of the strings (e.g. preserving the spaces). I've already tried many combinations but no success.

Answer (score 2):

I'd say

```
new_string = string.gsub(old_string, "^(| *)[A-Za-z]+", "%1prefix", 1)
```

where the `prefix` in `"%1prefix"` is the thing with which you want to replace the first part of the key. The `, 1` at the end is not strictly necessary because `^` anchors the pattern at the beginning of the line, but it will potentially allow `gsub` to do less work.

The basic trick is to capture the `|` and following spaces from the input string and use them (with `%1`) in the replacement.

Depending on the precise forms the keys are allowed to take, the `[A-Za-z]` set of allowed characters may need adjustment (such as `[A-Za-z_]` if keys can contain underscores). The crowbar method would be to use `[^0-9 =]` (i.e., anything but numbers, spaces and `=`), but I'm not sure I'd recommend it.

Note, by the way, that Lua [patterns](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#5.4.1) are not regular expressions (and somewhat less powerful).

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution (see function 'my' in example below):

```
t = {
    {"|house10=true"          , 'residence'},
    {"|car11 = house"         , 'auto'},
    {"| name    = car"        , 'label'},
    {"|     wow15  =   cat"   , 'owo'},
}

function my(s,myown)
  s = s:gsub('(|%s*)(%a+)(%d*%s*=%s*%a+)','%1'..myown..'%3')
  return s
end

for _,v in ipairs(t) do
  print(my(v[1],v[2]))
end
```